# Keras - CNN input shape incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on binary classification my code is working fine on **Keras Lstm** when I am working with CNN I am getting input shape incompatibility error.

this is the value error i am getting

**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_61 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 1)**

this is my cnn code using keras

```
model=Sequential()
inputBatch = inputBatch.reshape(24,30, 1)
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4,strides=None, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(inputBatch,ponlabel,batch_size=24,epochs=20,validation_data=(inputBatch, ponlabel))
```

**I am working on binary classification either it will be positive or either negative**

for reference this is my lstm code

```
inputBatch =inputBatch.reshape(24,30,1)
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(30, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(inputBatch,ponlabel,batch_size=24,epochs=100,verbose=1)
```

**inputBatch is something like this it is working on LSTM code but not working on CNN this is the input which I have used for training on both codes separately**

```
[[    0.  1288.  1288.  2214. 11266.  6923.   420.     0.     0.  8123.
      0.  7619.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0. 11516.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  9929. 11501.  6573. 11266.  7566.  9963.  4420. 10936.  3657.
   7050.     0.   408. 11501.  9988.  9963.  8455.  2879.  9322.  2047.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 11956.  5222.     0.     0. 12106.  6481.     0.  7093. 13756.
  12152.     0.     0.     0.     0. 10173.     0.  5173. 13756.  9371.
      0.  9956.     0.     0.  9716.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.   420.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 11501.  1916.  2073. 10936.  6312.     0. 10193. 10322.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  2879.  7852. 11501.  1934.   286. 11483.     0. 12004. 11118.
      0. 12007.  9917. 12111.  1520. 10364.     0.  8840.  4195.  2910.
  10773. 11386. 12117.  9321.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  7885.  7171.  1034. 11501.  3103.  5842.  4395. 11871.  3328.
   6719.  5407.  1087.  8935.  2937.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  8894.   450. 11516.  7353. 11501. 11502. 11499.     0.  1319.
  11693. 11501.  5735. 12111.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1087.  9565.    23.     0.  3045.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  5015. 11501.  3306. 12111.  9307.  5050. 11501.  3306.     0.
   3306. 12111.  1981. 11516.   615. 11516.     0.  3925. 11956.  9371.
   9013.  4395. 12111.  5048.     0.  3925.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1287.   420.  4070. 11087.  7410. 12186.  2387. 12111.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.   128.  2073. 10936.  6312.     0. 10193. 10322.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 10173.  9435.  1320.  9322. 12018.  1055.  8840.  6684. 12051.
   2879.     0. 12018.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1570.  5466.  9322.    34. 11480.  1356. 11270.   420.  2153.
  12006.  5157.  8840.  1055. 11516.  7387.  2356.  2163.  2879.  5541.
   9443.  7441.  1295.  5473.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  5014.     0.     0.  3651.  1087.    63.  6153.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 10608. 10855.  9562.     0.     0.     0.  4202.     0.     0.
      0. 10818. 10818.  5842.     0.  9963.     0. 11516. 10464.  7491.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  5952.  6133.   450.  7520.  5842.  3412. 10400.  3412.  2149.
   4891.  2979.  3456.   505.  9929. 11501.  9322.  1836. 11501. 12111.
   3435. 11105. 11266.   420.  9322.    34.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1570.  5466.  9322.    34. 11480.  1356. 11270.   420.  2153.
  12006.  5157.  8840.  1055. 11516.  7387.  2356.  2163.  2879.  5541.
   9443.  7441.  1295.  5473.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  7544.     0.  1709.   420. 10936.  5222.  5842. 10407.  6937.
  11329.  2937.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  7785.  8840.     0.   420.  8603. 12003.  2879.  1087.  2356.
   2390. 12111.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  8695.  8744.   420.  8840.  6697.  9267. 11516. 11203.  2260.
   8840.  7309.     0. 11100.  6041.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  9307. 12003.  2879.  6398.  9372.  4614.  5222.     0.     0.
   2879. 10364.  6923.  4709.  4860. 11871.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.  2844.  1287.   420. 11501.   610. 11501.   596.     0.
  12111.  3690.  6343.  9963.     0.     0.  8840.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
```

Comment: Can you also share the error message?

Comment: yes wait ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_61 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 1) @desa

Comment: What is the shape of ponlabel?

Comment: the shape of ponlabel is (24, 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the output shape, since you use an CNN, the output is 3D (samples, width, channels), and the Dense layer will operate on the last dimension, giving you a 3D output. But you want a 2D output, so you need to add a Flatten layer:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(30, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4,strides=None, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

You can compare the output shape of this model and your original model by doing `model.summary()`

Comment: Brother i have provided the lstm code for reference the problem is with the cnn code please read the question

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra Sure, but I am not your brother. You have the same issue with the CNN, let me update the question.

Comment: can you make an answer with CNN it will be helpful for me to understand

Comment: it worked . thanks i am accepting it did i have any problem with my lstm code?

Comment: I think you also need a Flatten layer before the last Dense layer.

Answer (score 0):

Such an error may arise when input images are not of the same size.

Add more information ( I could not comment to say that as I don't have enough rep), possibly including the full stack trace.

Comment: input batch is not an image it is a text

Comment: you can check it

Answer (score 0):

The incompatible input shape is due to `ponlabel`.  For the LSTM, it has shape (24,1).  But the CNN is using `binary_crossentropy` for the loss, so it would have two target classes.  This means for the CNN the `ponlabels` would need to have shape (24,2,1).

Comment: I have tried with both examples i have also rehaped the ponlabel while reshapping it is showing that cannot resize  error of 24 into (24,2,1) and i have also changed the loss function to MSE or Categorical Cross entropy both are not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either MSE or Categorical Cross entropy for your CNN loss

Comment: not working with both of them i am getting the same error